# Is there a dwarf god for the Light domain?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities

Is there a dwarven deity for whom the Light domain would be applicable? Obviously, with GM buy-in you can take any domain for any deity, but I'd prefer to create a thematically consistent character. I've been looking around, but the dwarves don't appear to have a sun god, or a fire god, or any of the usual suspects for Light domain clerics.

The setting is Forgotten Realms, and the game is D&D 5e. Since the only dwarven deity in a 5e book is Moradin, I'm open to anything from an earlier edition. Just including 5e on the question to avoid any gods who have been killed or otherwise removed from canon.

Also worth noting that while I'm open to answers like 'Moradin works for the Light domain because such-and-such', it's easy to see that Lathander (or, preferably, the dwarf version of him) is far more thematically appropriate.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With the release of Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes, there is a list on page 73 of dwarven deities and their domains. Berronar Truesilver and Tharmekhûl both have the Light domain. I'll leave my original answer below the break for reference in case future readers wouldn't prefer the two deities listed above.

---

Dugmaren Brightmantle seems like a good candidate. From the Wikipedia page:

> Dugmaren Brightmantle is the dwarf deity of scholarship, discovery, and invention. Dugmaren shares the Dwarven Mountain on the Outlands with Dumathoin and Vergadain. Dugmaren appears as an elderly dwarf with sparkling blue eyes.

His domain isn't strictly light, but those domains are probably more of a suggestion. It could be argued that Light would be a fitting domain for this deity. Discovery, knowledge, and enlightenment go hand-in-hand with light in certain deity systems. Alternatively, Marthammor Duin could be an option since that deity has an affinity for lightning.

Tharmekhûl could be an option as well due to being associated with fire and the light domain has quite a few fire spells.

Source: [Dwarf Deities on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarf_deities#Dungeons_.26_Dragons_5th_edition_.282014-.29)

Comment: I was on the verge of downvoting this when you added Tharmekhûl. A fire god definitely works with the Light domain, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Yeah, it struck me the instant after I originally posted. No problem, glad to help!

Comment: I think Marthammor Duin and Tharmekhûl deserve more substantial write-ups, akin to Dugmaren Brightmantle, and in particular [don’t signal your edits in text](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3454/4563).

Comment: With the release of Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes, we have confirmation that Tharmekhûl is indeed of the Light domain, but Dugmaren is considered only Knowledge, and Marthammor Duin is only Nature and Trickery.

Comment: @CTWind Thank you, I'll update my answer when I pick up the book. Should be soon.

Comment: Tharmekhûl's cleric's actions seem restrictive in the greater world of beings. They tend forges inside Meridian's temples. although they can have quest, by large they are a cleric amongst forges and their own kind.

Answer (score 11):

With the release of Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide, there are additional Dwarven gods now listed in a 5e sourcebook. The one likely of interest to you is Berronar Truesilver, goddess of hearth and home, as she is the only god in the Dwarven Pantheon section on p.22 with the Light domain listed.

Sadly, SCAG doesn't have detailed sections for the non-Faerunian Pantheon gods so there's no additional information to glean about her there, though materials from older editions may be of use. The only additional information about her I see in SCAG is a small blurb on p.104 describing her as "the Revered Mother, [...] goddess of hearth and home, of honesty and faithfulness, and of oaths, loyalty, and honor".

As of the release of Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes, we have a slightly expanded pantheon listing that includes one additional god with the light domain, Tharmekhûl, whose province is "Fire, forges, molten rock".

The book doesn't go into further detail about Tharmekhûl, but it *does* delve a bit further into Berronar. It describes her as the one who "lays out the rules for managing a Dwarven clan", providing "the bonds that create dwarven society and culture". It also describes her priests as being the ones in charge of arranging marriages in an attempt to strengthen the clan from one generation to the next.